# Choice of gauge for vector potential in Schroedinger Equation

Tags: magnetic-fields, schroedinger-equation, gauge

When we learn about the Schroedinger equation of a particle in a magnetic field, we are told

$ \displaystyle
\frac{(p-eA/c)^2}{2m}\Psi = E\Psi
$

The momentum operator is $-i\hbar \nabla$.  The square of $p-eA/c$ can in principle generate a term $-ie\hbar/c \nabla\cdot A$.  But we are then told we can make a gauge choice of $A$ such that this term is zero and can be ignored.

But it seems to me that if we, for whatever reason, choose some gauge where $\nabla\cdot A \neq 0$, we get a completely different equation.  As I was wondering about this, I thought perhaps this extra term would create changes in $\Psi$, but changes that wouldn't be observable.  Perhaps $\Psi^*\Psi$ would be unaffected.  But as I keep thinking on this, this seems unlikely.  It seems to me that the $\nabla\cdot A$ term would have some sort of observable effect on $\Psi$.

But if that is the case, a gauge condition in quantum mechanics won't be a mere choice, but must be selected to conform to experimental results, that is, to what scientists observe in $\Psi^*\Psi$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I am not going to word this properly, so sorry about this, but have a look through  a worked example of an electromagnetism text book or on the net. You are correct, from memory, that you do "pay a price" in choosing a convenient gauge, in that there is a phase change related factor in the result.

Comment: And in QM, these factors leave the probability untouched, because they are complex. But again from guessing/memory, this phase factor is the basis for force carriers in QFT. Best of luck getting a proper math answer, I self study, so take please take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to work backward here.  The Schrodinger equation with the full Hamiltonian for a particle in an electromagnetic field is

$$ H_0\Psi = \left[\frac{(p-eA/c)^2}{2m} + e\phi\right]\Psi = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \Psi$$

We can apply a local phase shift $\Psi \rightarrow \exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\lambda\right]\Psi$ without changing the state of the system (the constants have been written for convenience).  This is true for constant $\lambda$ of course, but we *demand* that it also be true for $\lambda=\lambda(x,t)$.

In that case, the left hand side becomes

$$\left[\frac{(-i\hbar \nabla - eA/c)^2}{2m}+e\phi\right]\exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\lambda\right] \Psi = \exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\right] \cdot \left[\frac{(-i \hbar \nabla - eA/c +e(\nabla\lambda)/c)^2}{2m}+e\phi\right]\Psi$$

while the right hand side becomes
$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\lambda\right]\Psi = \exp\left[\frac{ie}{\hbar c}\lambda\right]\left[i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \frac{e}{c}\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t}\right] \Psi $$

If we define then transformed potentials
$$A' = A - \nabla \lambda$$
$$\phi' = \phi +\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t}$$

Then we recover our previous equation.  The lesson to take home from this is that applying the gauge transformation to $A$ and $\phi$ is equivalent to multiplying the state by a phase factor, albeit one that changes in space and time.

---

Some people get hung up on the fact that the Hamiltonian you used sets the scalar potential $\phi=0$.  We can always do that if we wish, but it's important to remember that this is part of our choice in gauge.

Comment: @j-murray   So it was just a phase shift after all.  I guess I should have worked the math out in detail instead of just staring at the equation!  Thanks!

Comment: @bob.sacamento No problem.  In fairness to you, working this out can get pretty gory and disgusting if you don't know where things are going ahead of time ;)