What is the Hamiltonian of an atom in a magnetic field?
I am working on developing a science fair project analyzing the Zeeman Effect using Perturbation Theory. I need to find the Hamiltonian of an atom in a magnetic field, but I am unsure how to write it. Could someone please proofread this Hamiltonian or provide one for me?
$$H = H₀ + H'$$
$H₀$ is the unperturbed atomic Hamiltonian and $H'$ is the perturbation due to the magnetic field

You might find these articles interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction for $H_0$, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeeman_effect#Theoretical_presentation for $H'$ (called $V_M$ there).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could someone please proofread this Hamiltonian? Calling the magnetic perturbation $H’$ is fine, but that doesn’t convey anything about how it operates on the wavefunction. You’re not going to be able to calculate the Zeeman shift with just that.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713227/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/294228/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/349053/226902

If you want to describe particles in the presence of the electromagnetic field, you need to pay attention to the spin of the particle.
For a non-relativistic electron the Spin-$1/2$ wave function is a function
$$\Psi: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb C^2$$. So the wave function is now $\mathbb C^2$ valued. For $n$-electrons the wave function is a map
$$\Psi: \mathbb R^{3n} \to (\mathbb C^2)^{\otimes n}$$.
Let's focus on the one-particle case. The Pauli equation is given by
$$i \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t} 
=( \frac{(- i \hbar \vec  {\nabla} - q \vec A)^2}{2m} + q \Psi )- g \frac{ q \hbar}{2m} \frac{\vec \sigma}{2} \cdot \vec B \Psi\,,
$$
where $\vec \sigma$ are the Pauli matrices. The right hand side can be identified with $\hat H \Psi$
